# GameStudio : How to remove object after delay

Tags: game-maker, timer, objects

When you pick an item in the inventory and drop it to `obj_item_ground`, this item is send to the ground. That's fine.
I want to add a delay to this item to destroy it, but if I drop 2 items to the ground, only the last is destroy.

Question : How can I create one timer by item dropped ?

**Step :**

`obj_inventory` : on Create event

```
 instance_create(0, 0, obj_item_ground);
```

`obj_item_ground` : on Create event

```
initialTime = 5;
time = 5;
ground = -1;
```

on Alarm[0] event; if timer is less than 0, object is destroy.

```
if (time > 0) {
    time -= 1;
    alarm[0] = 30;
} else {
    with (ground) {
        instance_destroy();
    }
}
```

on Left Pressed event :

```
if (mouseItem != -1) {
    scr_item_ground_timer();
}
```

*mouseItem is item I drag to the obj_item_ground.*

`scr_item_ground_timer()` :

Here I create the instance of object dropped to the ground and start the alarm[0] timer.

```
scr_inventory_item_drop(mouseItem);

for (i = 0; i < mouseQuantity; i++) {
 ground = instance_create(obj_player.x + random_range(-30, 4), obj_player.y + random_range(-12, 0), mouseItem);
}
alarm[0] = 30;
mouseItem = -1;
```

*scr_inventory_item_drop is just to clear the array which contains the object dropped.*

Comment: Why are you doing `with (ground) instance_destroy();`? This means the ground will be destroyed, not the object that is the owner of the timer.

Comment: ground is the item's instance_create (in scr_item_ground_timer) and it currently destroy the object on the ground when the timer is 0. It's a bad practice ?
Maybe this var is badly named. Var "ground" is the object dropped.
I just need to put unique timer to each "ground" dropped to the ground.

Comment: Yeah, you should let the responsibility of destroying items dropped on the ground for themselves, not delegate it to someone else. I'll write an answer detailing more soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, if you handle the destruction of items dropped to the ground in the inventor object, you won't be able to handle multiple items.

Make sure to let the responsibility of destroying the items on ground for themselves, that's it, each object will have it's own alarm. It's not a bad design, and it doesn't cause lag as well because it's just a single counter that gets decreased every step.

So, for every possible `mouse_item` I recommend that you create a parent object, let's call it `obj_droppable`.
In This `obj_droppable` you should set the alarm.

`obj_droppable` Create:

```
alarm[0] = 60; //or whatever time you need for it to stay on ground
```

`obj_droppable` Alarm 0:

```
instance_destroy();
```

Comment: Ok, so I can remove the Create and Alarm[0] events in obj_item_ground ? And put your new object to obj_item parent ?

Comment: @guish Exactly.